# where to configure - Available for Customer Portal metadata?

Tags: metadata-api, high-volume-portal

my custom objects are not pushing with the "Available for Customer Portal" flag set to true. In the sandbox I change it, then do a refresh from server on my custom profile as well as the object and I dont see any changes. So my question, where can I set this in metadata and what do I need to change to package.xml to get these changes synced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the metadata can be modified to reflect many SF settings and configurations, it doesn't cover everything that can be done manually in the SF Admin screens.  It appears that the "Available for Customer Portal" setting on a custom object is one of these items - you're going to have to do it manually in every SF environment where you push your code.

Would definitely be nice to have this feature!!  (if you're listening salesforce - hint, hint)

Answer (score 0):

These things most likely will need to be set in the "application" that I assume you've created for your portal. If you're not getting any error messages when you do your sync with production (right now there's a known issue some of us are having with metadata and package.xml in our orgs), sometimes you need to "bite the bullet" and simply go in and make those revisions in the production org to the objects, apps and/or profiles.

You also may discover upon investigation that the profiles are actually there but aren't in use or assigned in the production org (you may see an old, a new or renamed version when you check). In my experience, updates to profiles don't tend to transfer very well. In fact, Eclipse normally gives you a warning when you select profile metadata for inclusion in a project about some of the problems that can occur.

Comment: I tried creating the app, but still cant find a way to get this flag set.

Comment: Have you tried deploying everything to production from the sandbox instead of using the eclipse IDE?

Comment: No, sorry to be clear my issues is I cant find anyway to autodeploy this flag either via the ide or ant migration tool. Of course I can do it manually in the sandbox or production.

Comment: If you can select it for deployment in an outbound change set from the sandbox, I don't understand why you can't select it for deployment from Eclipse. If you can and it's not transferring, there's a known issue with [eclipse](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SwXNAA0) that you may want to check and see if it applies to you. In getting the link, I see there's a [related issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SzoNAAS) that may also apply to your situation.